# Stackstatus.net is no longer a blog. Can we stop calling it that?

Tags: feature-request, wording, offline, stackstatus

I was greeted with the "offline for maintenance" page just now. It appears to have been a short service interruption, as the page I was looking for loaded just fine 2 minutes later.

Looking at the offline page I noticed that https://www.stackstatus.net is still referred to as a blog. While this was true in the past when the page was hosted on [Tumblr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumblr), I don't feel that the current system, [FireHydrant](https://firehydrant.com/), really is a blog.

So can we stop calling it a blog and find a more appropriate name?

Perhaps we should call it status page, or something similar?

[image: Screenshot of the offline for maintenance page that reads: "We are currently offline for maintenance - Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns into an extended outage, we will tweet updates from @StackStatus or post details on the status blog." A red freehand circle is drawn around blog.]

Comment: Changing it to status page might work, yeah.

Comment: Agreed, it says "Welcome to Stack Overflow's status page" on the page itself. :)